# Replacing quotes and words in parentheses with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, title, movie

I'm struggling to match a few movie titles i have in a weird format. Some of the titles are wrapped in quotes and some begin with `#` or `$`, and most of them end with the release year at the end (otherwise ????).

I'm trying to replace this:

```
"Ein Engel für alle" (2005) {Katzenjammer (#2.5)}   ????
#"Sospecha" (1963) {El caso del viejo del Tibet}     1963
MTV Europe Music Awards 1998 (1998) (TV)        1998
"Hotel Cæsar" (1998) {(#12.26)}             1998
$Am Rande - Sechs Kapitel über AIDS in der Ukraine (2006)   2006
```

...to this:

```
Ein Engel für alle, ????
Sospecha, 1963
MTV Europe Music Awards 1998, 1998
Hotel Cæsar, 1998
Am Rande - Sechs Kapitel über AIDS in der Ukraine, 2006
```

...and if possible, get the release year somehow. In the example I just put a comma, but if you can't get the release date just leave it and I'll get it another way.

I'm a complete newbie in regular expressions but I still tried to do it with no luck. If anyone can give me a hand I'd really appreciate it!

---

**Edit**

To make it less confusing:

1. Remove everything wrapped in `()` or `{}`.
2. Remove the `$` or `#` in the beginning of the string.
3. IF the title is wrapped in quotes, remove them.
4. Either leave it like this, or use some kind of grouping to get the release date at the end of the string to a separate variable?

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This isn't suspicious at all.

Comment: You start your question by telling us that there are many formats the lines could be in, then only give us an example of two of them. We can't work under these conditions!

Comment: Why is it suspicious? I described the different formats in the post. I awnt to remove all quotes/parantheses/#, and also everything wrapped in () or {}, and possibly extract the last digits to a seperate string. Do you need more information? Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: You did not describe the different formats sufficiently. And it's suspicious because, well, lists of movies from the internet tend to be!

Comment: Well is it enough now or do you need more? I gave you an example that shows exactly what parts i want to extract, i think it's clear what i want now. Please help if you can!

Comment: You're still not providing _any_ examples of the majority of the formats you have told us exist.

Comment: Yes i have! The titles are all the same except some of them begin with $ or #, and some are in quotes, just like i said. In the examples you see the before->after results... Anyhow, see my edit, i added some info to make it easier.

Comment: You haven't shown us any beginning in `$` or `#`, or any without quotes. And where did this idea of wrapping in `()`/`{}` come from? There are no examples of that, either.

Comment: make more example. If you can provide all the possible example you could get the original string title. Make the example with $ too

Comment: Take a look now. The examples showed above are the all the formats i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp should be

```
$regexp = '[\W]*([\w- üæöä]+)[\W^-].*([\d?]{4})';
```

Comment: "Some of the titles are wrapped in qoutes and some begin with # or $" "most of them end with the release year at the end (otherwise ????)." You should read the question, marc.

Comment: This is what the first paragraph says, but all other parts of the question tell me that this regexp will work. If he do not specifies his question further, this answer is valid.

Comment: Katie is a girl's name, and if you wish to selectively ignore parts of the question to make your answer easier then that's your choice, but I don't think that this is useful to the OP.

Comment: Hmm, a little bit of tweaking left though. As i said some of (but not all) titles are wrapped in quotes, but i would still like to extract those titles. I don't want to include the quotes in the title. Also, i don't want the year in parentheses, it's not always correct. I want the release date at the end of the row. I want to remove everything wrapped in () or {}. Sorry for the mess...

Comment: @Katie: The regexp now is very generic: first some non-letters (optional), then some letters, that are the title, then one non-letter character like " or (, than everything gets ignored except the last 2 digits. You can evaluate it using Jenox's code.

Comment: Yes, i see. Please see my update for more information. A bit off topic but i use gskinner.com/RegExr to test regular expressions.. it's pretty neat.

Comment: It matches all of your given titles.

Comment: @marc: This is why I have a serious problem with the question as stated: she hasn't provided examples for all of the described cases, and now your answer has fallen foul of that.

Comment: However, the question has improved. It probably had not without someone providing an answer that fits the question but not what the OP wants :)

Comment: I think you both missed my update, sorry. I have examples of **all** cases now. Not that i think it's needed, i only added two examples with $ abd # in the beginning. Is it ok now?

Comment: What of the titles do you believe do not fit my regexp? I cant find anythign that does not match. Please first check and then critizise!

Comment: @marc: This now satisfies a year of "12?4", which is not valid.

Comment: I have checked. Every time i've checked you've updated your expression somehow. Right now, for example, it matches the all examples. I want to remove/exclude everything in () or {}, not even that is working now. Or maybe it's just not working for me? I'm using gskinner.com/RegExr to test them but i'll try with PHP just to be sure.

Comment: Such a year is not specified and I dont believe that this will ever happen

Comment: Katie: Yes it do not replaces, but you can get the results from the sections. In your RegExr hover on the match. You will see the title and the year getting displayed. Use Jenoxs code in php and you will get these sections.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. That website appareantly isn't reliable. Thank you, and sorry for the huge mess! (edit: Oh that makes me seem even more stupid! It's a good site. Thanks again!)

Comment: @marc: That's hardly the point. Your solution is non-robust and thus not fit-for-purpose as a pattern matching algorithm. It is also missing the steps for retrieving capture groups and presenting the desired output; in particular, you lose `"????"` from the input and would have to conditionally reconstruct it.

Comment: Imho it is even more robust because it will fit to any title that may come.

Comment: Your definition of "robust" is broken; a year of `"12?4"` would be **invalid** as per the OP's specification.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this script:

```
<?php
$inputs = Array(
        '"Ein Engel für alle" (2005) {Katzenjammer (#2.5)}   ????',
        '#"Sospecha" (1963) {El caso del viejo del Tibet}     1963',
        'MTV Europe Music Awards 1998 (1998) (TV)        1998',
        '"Hotel Cæsar" (1998) {(#12.26)}             1998',
        '$Am Rande - Sechs Kapitel über AIDS in der Ukraine (2006)   2006'
);

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
        $matches = Array();
        if (!preg_match('/^(?:\$|#)?(?:"(.+?)"|(.+?)) \(\d{4}\) .* (\d{4}|\?{4})$/', $input, $matches))
                continue;

        print $matches[1] . $matches[2] . ", " . $matches[3] . "\n";
}
?>
```

[Output](http://www.ideone.com/zRRRO):

```
Ein Engel für alle, ????
Sospecha, 1963
MTV Europe Music Awards 1998, 1998
Hotel Cæsar, 1998
Am Rande - Sechs Kapitel über AIDS in der Ukraine, 2006
```

This should fit your given rules precisely and accurately (though it does not use your proposed methodological steps, which do not really fit a pattern matching solution).

Let's take a closer look at that regex:

```
/                 # start of regex
^                 # starting delimiter and start-of-input
(?:\$|#)?         # $ or # (but don't capture)
(?:               # (don't capture the outer group)
   "(.+?)"|(.+?)  # title either in quotes or not
)
#\(\d{4}\)        # the inner date (delimits the title when the title has no quotes)
.*                # any other inner fluff
(\d{4}|\?{4})     # either four digits, or four question marks
$                 # the end-of-input must immediately follow
/                 # end of regex
```

Comment: That's ok, i know you can't do it in the order i described, it was more of a simple description for you. Marc already gave me the answer, but thank you for the insight to the regex, really informative!

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = '"Ein Engel für alle" (2005) {Katzenjammer (#2.5)}   ????
"Sospecha" (1963) {El caso del viejo del Tibet}     1963
MTV Europe Music Awards 1998 (1998) (TV)        1998
"Hotel Cæsar" (1998) {(#12.26)}             1998
Am Rande - Sechs Kapitel über AIDS in der Ukraine (2006)    2006';

preg_match_all('#(.*?) \(([0-9]+)\)#i', $string, $matches);
$count = count($matches[0]);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $title = preg_replace('#["\#\$]#us', '', $matches[1][$i]);
    echo "$title, {$matches[2][$i]}"."<br />";
}
```

Result:

```
Ein Engel für alle , 2005
Sospecha , 1963
MTV Europe Music Awards 1998 , 1998
Hotel Cæsar , 1998
Am Rande - Sechs Kapitel über AIDS in der Ukraine , 2006
```

Comment: I did. My comment is a link that demonstrates the brokenness.

Comment: I've pasted wrong code, should work now as in Result, thanks.

Comment: [Yep, better](http://www.ideone.com/7u5tR), though you have an extra space before the comma and the inputs in your answer are still not right! :)

Comment: OK, and what if the title actually _did_ have a space?!

Comment: It won't :) If it does, it should be in quotes. If you see space in title it is probably bad input by the user.

Comment: How do you know it won't? Was that in the specification? No. Don't mangle the user's input then attempt to retro-actively "fix" it later according to a narrow view of what that input "should" or "will" be: that's how unexpected bugs creep in.

Comment: Ok, I have removed trim, and added space in regexp, that shouldn't change input, by specification as you have said.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$data = '"Ein Engel für alle" (2005) {Katzenjammer (#2.5)}   ????';
$year;
$title;

if (preg_match('#(\d{4})$#', $data, $matches))
{
    $year = $matches[1];
}
if (preg_match('#^(?:"(.*)")|(.*)\s+\(\d{4}\)#', $data, $matches))
{
    $title = ($matches[2] ? $matches[2] : $matches[1]);
}
```

Edited my answer to fit your needs. ;)

Comment: This now _only_ extracts the release date, and only if there's no four-digit number in the title at that.

Comment: That's what she wants. She wants the date at the end of the string. Added the title, too.

Comment: So close! I don't want the year in parentheses. There are two dates in the title, there's one in parentheses and one without at the end. I want to remove everything wrapped in () and {}, so the date in parentheses should get removed, right? And also i don't want to keep the quotes around the name, i just said some of them have quotes and some don't... but thank you, almost done!

Comment: @Jenox: The examples she gave makes it clear that the desired output is "Title, Year".

Comment: That is not correct Tomalak. I quote: "And if possible, get the release year somehow. In the example i just put a comma, but if you can't get the release date just leave it and i'll get it another way."

Comment: The year returned by my code isn't in parantheses. It is the four digits at the end of the string. The title also gets computed correctly. Use $new = $title.", ".$year; to obtain what you want.

Comment: @Katie: Right, so you _definitely_ want the title and the date is optional. Jenox's answer seems to only give you one or the other.

Comment: No it doesn't. I just named the last var incorrectly. Edited.

Comment: @Jenox: You have syntax errors, and even when those are fixed [your solution does not handle the leading `#` and `$` cases](http://www.ideone.com/xwUgH).